# Is there a way to retrieve the HTML code of a webpage which is generated based on input values on a different webpage?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the HTML code of https://www.example.com/mcqRegionList which otherwise "doesn't exist", but is generated based on the value selected on "Select Level" dropdown menu on the page https://www.example.com/mcqLevelList.

Snapshot of the HTML code of https://www.example.com/mcqLevelList is like:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#mcqLevel").change(function() {
            var levelCode= $('#mcqLevel option:selected').val();
             $("#levelCode").val(levelCode);
             $('#mcqMasterForm').attr('action', 'mcqRegionList');
             $("#mcqMasterForm").submit();
        });

        $("#mcqRegion").change(function() {
            var levelCode= $('#mcqLevel option:selected').val();
            var regionCode= $('#mcqRegion option:selected').val();
             $("#levelCode").val(levelCode);
             $("#regionCode").val(regionCode);
             $('#mcqMasterForm').attr('action', 'mcqCityList');
             $("#mcqMasterForm").submit();
        });

        $("#mcqCity").change(function() {
            var levelCode= $('#mcqLevel option:selected').val();
            var regionCode= $('#mcqRegion option:selected').val();
            var cityCode= $('#mcqCity option:selected').val();
             $("#levelCode").val(levelCode);
             $("#regionCode").val(regionCode);
             $("#cityCode").val(cityCode);
             $('#mcqMasterForm').attr('action', 'mcqCenterList');
             $("#mcqMasterForm").submit();
        });
    });

    function downloadMcqFile(levelCode,regionCode,cityCode,centerCode)
    {
         $("#levelCode").val(levelCode);
         $("#regionCode").val(regionCode);
         $("#cityCode").val(cityCode);
         $("#centerCode").val(centerCode);
         $('#mcqMasterForm').attr('action', "downloadMcqwisePdfFile");
         $("#mcqMasterForm").submit();

    }

    $('#example').DataTable( {
         scrollY: '29vh',
         scrollX: true,
         "searching": false,
         "ordering": false,
         scrollCollapse: true,
         paging: false,
         bInfo: false
    } );
</script>
```

And then we have:

```
<thead>
  <tr align='center'>
    <th style="width: 30%">Select Level</th>
    <th style="width: 30%"> Select Region</th>
    <th style="width: 30%"> Select City</th>
  </tr>
  <tr align='center'>
    <th>
      <select name="levelCode" id="mcqLevel">
        <option value="-1">Select Level</option>
        <option value="05">UPPER</option>
        <option value="03">LOWER</option>
        <option value="01">MIDDLE</option>
        <option value="02">LEFT</option>
        <option value="04">RIGHT</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th>
      <select>
        <option value="">Select Region</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th>
      <select>
        <option value="">Select City</option>
      </select>
    </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

So far, I've tried this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

Stdriver = webdriver.Firefox()
Stdriver.get('https://www.example.com/mcqLevelList')

Select(Stdriver.find_element_by_tag_name("select")).select_by_index(2)
Stdriver.get('https://www.example.com/mcqRegionList')
Stdriver.find_element_by_id('mcqRegion').select_by_index(2)
```

However, getting an error message at the last line:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="mcqRegion"]
```

Comment: What are trying to locate from that page? Are you sure it's id is equal to 'mcqRegion'?

Comment: Well, it's solved now. The issue was, the page was taking time to get downloaded. However, the python script was looking for the element too quick, even before the page was completely downloaded. Therefore the error was occurring!